# order independent transparency - memory barrier

Tags: opengl, rendering

The example I was reading comes from the opengl red book. 
Source code is here: https://github.com/openglredbook/examples/blob/master/src/11-oit/11-oit.cpp

I read about image load store is incoherent memory access, and does not guarantee ordering between 2 rendering command. https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Memory_Model
When I read source code for this algorithm, I see no mentioning of memory barrier.
So do I actually need to call memory barrier between the rendering command that sort the fragments and store them, and the rendering command that renders the quad?

Answer (score 4):

For your general question, yes, you need an explicit memory barrier between the two operations.

On a more personal note, please stop looking at that code. I'm seeing many dubious things beyond just the lack of a barrier: the mapping of a buffer for the sole purpose of writing a single integer, a call to `glTexSubImage2D` that's sure to give an error because `NULL` is not a valid pointer parameter, etc.